# NHibernate data is out of sync in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I use NHibernate in a multi-threaded scenario. It's a test that performs the following actions.

1. (Start a multi-threaded server.)
2. Send a request to the server. The server creates a new `Foo` object with state `A` and stores it in the DB using NHibernate.
3. Set state `B` for the newly created `Foo` object.
4. Send a request to the server. The server gets `Foo` from the DB using NHibernate, reads its state (should be `B`) and acts accordingly.
5. (Stop the server.)

Now my problem is that sporadically (in 1 - 2% of the cases) in step 4 the server reads state `A` when it should read `B` and the test fails. **What am I doing wrong here?**

NHibernate sessions are retrieved via `CurrentSessionContext` which is set to *thread static*. I use Fluent NHibernate, but I guess this doesn't matter.

### Edit

Details about the server:
The server is a simple TCP server. When started it creates a new <del>thread</del> **task** to wait for incoming connections. When a new connection is accepted it creates another <del>thread</del> **task** to process the request from the connection and send a response. The the processing <del>thread</del> **task** terminates.

The server uses `Task.Factory.StartNew()` to create new <del>threads</del> **tasks**.

### Edit 2

I wrote a small NUnit test to reproduce this behavior. It fails with

> Expected: Open But was:  Initialized

on the first iteration.

```
[Test]
[Explicit]
public void NHibernateProblem()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var identifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var session1 = Database.GetCurrentSession();
        using (var dbTransaction = session1.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var transaction1 = new Transaction
            {
                Identifier = identifier,
                Status = TransactionStatus.Initialized
            };

            session1.SaveOrUpdate(transaction1);
            dbTransaction.Commit();
        }

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var session2 = Database.GetCurrentSession();
            using (var dbTransaction = session2.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var transaction2 = session2
                    .QueryOver<Transaction>()
                    .Where(t => t.Identifier == identifier)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

                transaction2.Status = TransactionStatus.Open;

                session2.SaveOrUpdate(transaction2);
                dbTransaction.Commit();
            }
        }).Wait();

        var session3 = Database.GetCurrentSession();
        using (var dbTransaction = session3.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var transaction3 = session3
                .QueryOver<Transaction>()
                .Where(t => t.Identifier == identifier)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            dbTransaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("iteration {0}", i);

            Assert.That(transaction3.Status, Is.EqualTo(TransactionStatus.Open));
        }
    }
}
```

`Database.GetCurrentSession()` looks like this:

```
public virtual ISession GetCurrentSession()
{
    if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(SessionFactory))
    {
        var currentSession = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        return currentSession;
    }

    var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Always;
    session.CacheMode = CacheMode.Ignore;
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    return session;
}
```

I believe the mappings are less relevant.

Comment: I think you're gonna have to show what you're doing in much more detail for anyone to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Also, you say "multi-threaded", but it's not clear where or how these multiple threads are involved.

Comment: @OskarBerggren I tried to describe it as it's very hard to strip down the entire application to a few lines of code. Also I mention the multithreaded server as i suppose it has something to do with synchronization of sessions or states among them.

Comment: Well, there is most probably some sort of race condition here, but that cannot be found from such a high-level description. How many requests do you have concurrently? Do you see the issue even if all requests run sequentially instead of concurrently? How do you manage the sessions (lifetime)? Caching? Etc...

Comment: See my test. I hope this is better than my high-level description.

Comment: In the previous edit I was missing a `.Wait()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the unit test shown, session3 will be the same as session1, and therefore transaction3 will be the same object instance as transaction1, and it will therefore still show the values as they were when the transaction-object was added.

The query in the third part will hit the database, but NHibernate will see that the fetched object is already loaded and return the instance that the session already holds in memory. It will normally not overwrite the values in the object.

Comment: Okay, this somehow makes sense. What is your suggestion for this? Should I go with `.Refresh()` after every load from the DB? Did you see my config of `CacheMode`? I thought this will cause NHibernate to ignore those  object *"hold in memory"*?

Comment: BTW: `session3.Refresh(transaction3);` will cause the test to pass!

Comment: @DioF What are you really trying to accomplish here? Is writing the test case the true problem or is this just a simplified model of the real problem? Because the solution may differ. In the test case you can either use Refresh or make sure that part 1 and 3 uses different sessions. Btw, ALL iterations of the loop will use the same session instance for session1 and session3 (totalt number of sessions will be (1+100). Is that really what you want to test? I assume production code would look different and so the solution could be different.

Comment: Without looking it up, I believe the CacheMode is about second-level cache. First-level cache is always present (unless you use stateless session), as it's the feature that manages object identity in the session (simplistically, each row in the database should correspond to at most one object in memory (per session)), and it's also used to detect any changes that needs to be persisted.

Comment: Yep. I was assuming sessions would be smarter regarding synchronization. But now it's clearer to me what a session does - and what it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In a server general practice is to create a session per request, and to start the transaction at the beginning of the request. When the request is about to complete transaction is either committed or rolled back depending on the result.

In your test it does not actually simulate this scenario, and it uses the same session for request 1 and request 3 where it will never be the case in actual scenario.

So, to test the actual scenario, you can create a new session for session 3.

Comment: You are right. And in fact I am doing so - or at least i was thinking doing so. The problem why this happens *sporadically* is that I create a `Task` and not a `Thread`. So a `Task` will not necessarily result in a new `Thread` which is why *sporadically* the `Task` runs in the main `Thread` using an already existing session which holds the object with the *old* state. Now I use `new Thread().Start()` and it always passes.